# TryUpdateModel - why does it update two objects?

Tags: asp.net

I have method called after update item in grid:

```
public void GridView1_UpdateItem(int noteId)
{
    Notes itemToEdit = context.Notes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NoteId == noteId);
    Notes originalItem = context.Notes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NoteId == noteId);

    TryUpdateModel(itemToEdit); //it should update only object itemToEdit
}
```

Why `TryUpdateModel(itemToEdit)` updates also object originalItem? Object originalItem has new values from form but it should have old values.

Comment: Both of them are basically the same - itemToEdit and originalItem refer to same memory object. Try with e.g. context.Notes.ToList().FirstOrDefault() and see what happens.

Comment: show me your page_load event as well

Comment: @Ozren with context.Notes.ToList().FirstOrDefault() I also have new values in object and I want old values :/

Comment: @Rahul my Page_load event is empty

Answer (score 0):

Your update function is getting old values may be the reason that you are not using `Page.IsPostBack` Property in `Page_Load` like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
        // Your code..
        }
    }
```

Comment: my Page_Load event is empty